# as3 Cannot create same SimpleButton at the same time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, simplebutton

I make a tile-matching game, and the operation is picking three numbers of 3x3 grid that show 1~9, and if the sum of the three numbers are as same as the goal of target number( usually 6~24, 6=1+2+3, and 24=7+8+9), then the three numbers will disappear. While the three numbers disappear, three new random numbers will show up.

In my LIBRARY, I create 9 `SimpleButton` called btnO1~O9 as `SimpleButton` class respectively, and another 9 `SimpleButton` called btnC1~C9 as another class.

My idea to fulfill my game is:
In the initial of the game, there are 18 `SimpleButton` be created in the screen, half parts  are btnO1~btnO9, and another half parts are btnC1~btnC9, and I let btnC1~btnC9 be hidden. So it is like that:

[image: Initial of the game]

When user press the button, it will turn to green color to let people know they pick up the number, like this:

[image: Pick up a number]

Then just click one more time to cancel your option.

If the three number be picked up can match the goal showed above, then the three numbers will disappear, and your score will be added 500 points each time:

[image: Match is correct and three numbers disappear]

So far my game be made just like what I want, however, if I try to create new three numbers to take place the three disappeared numbers, I find that it will either show nothing be added or only one or two numbers be added......

While trying the reason of causing the problem, I found that if the numbers are same `SimpleButton`, then it cannot be create.

For example, if I have created btnO1 in the scene, then if I try to create another btnO1, even I set the different name of btnO1( the `SimpleButton`), to actionscript( I not sure whether it only occur in 3 or both 2 and 3), that will cause error or exception not show in debug window.

Is anyone know what's the problem of create same customized `SimpleButton` at the same time or is it can be soved?

My code is:

```
var goal:int=6+Math.random()*19;                // match number, 6~24 usually
txGoal.text=""+goal;
var numArr:Array=new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);  // original 1~9 number
var pickArr:Array=new Array(0,0,0);             // array to find the position be clicked
var pickNum:Array=new Array(0,0,0);             // array to find the number be clicked
var count:int=0;                                // index for above array
var sum:int=0;                                  // check with goal
var score:int=0;                                
var canClick:Boolean=true;                      // can click only after anime stop
initNum();                                      // first round is 1~9, after first round will random
function initNum()
{
    for(var i:int=0;i<numArr.length;i++)
    {
        origin(numArr[i],i);
        clicked(numArr[i],i); // the trick for if number be clicked will show green one
    }
}

var bub:int=0;
var bubbleT:Timer = new Timer(25);
var newW:int=0;
var newH:int=0;
// Timer to do animation of disappear
bubbleT.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, bubbleoutHandler);
function bubbleoutHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    bub++;
    for(var i:int=0;i<pickArr.length;i++)
    {
        var nam:String=pickArr[i]+"_"+pickNum[i];
        if(bub==1)
        {
            getChildByName("c"+nam).removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,cHandler); // remove the event of the three numbers
            removeChild(getChildByName("c"+nam)); // remove the three numbers
            getChildByName("o"+nam).visible=true; // show original number that do animation of disappear
            newW=getChildByName("o"+nam).width;
            newH=getChildByName("o"+nam).height;
            getChildByName("o"+nam).width=newW*(0.8); // change bubble's size smaller at first
            getChildByName("o"+nam).height=newH*(0.8);
        }
        else
        {
            var scale:Number=1+(bub*0.05);
            getChildByName("o"+nam).width=newW*scale; // change bubble's size bigger gradually as bubble will blow up
            getChildByName("o"+nam).height=newH*scale;
        }

        if(bub==4)
        {
            getChildByName("o"+nam).removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,oHandler); // remove event of origin numbers
            removeChild(getChildByName("o"+nam)); // remove numbers as it disappeared
        }
    }
    if(bub==4)
    {
        count=0;
        sum=0;
        bub=0;
        bubbleT.stop(); // the three numbers disappeared
        newT.start(); // try to new three numbers
    }
}
var bnew:int=0;
// timer to do animation of create new numbers
var newT:Timer = new Timer(100);
newT.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, bubblenewHandler);
function bubblenewHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    bnew++;
    for(var i:int=0;i<pickArr.length;i++)
    {
        var newnum:int=Math.random()*9+1; // random number from 1~9
        var newpos=parseInt(pickArr[i]); // the new number should appear at original place
        origin(newnum,newpos);
        clicked(newnum,newpos);
    }
    // Originally do animation of adding new numbers, just change bubble size
        //var nam:String=pickArr[i]+"_"+pickNum[i];
        //var scale:Number=(bnew*0.2);
        //getChildByName("o"+nam).width=newW*scale;
        //getChildByName("o"+nam).height=newH*scale;

    if(bnew>=2)
    {
        canClick=true;
        bnew=0;
        newT.stop();
    }
}
// the function of create numbers( SimpleButton)
function origin(n:int,i:int)
{
    var o:SimpleButton;
    if(n==1)
        o=new btnO1();
    else if(n==2)
        o=new btnO2();
    else if(n==3)
        o=new btnO3();
    else if(n==4)
        o=new btnO4();
    else if(n==5)
        o=new btnO5();
    else if(n==6)
        o=new btnO6();
    else if(n==7)
        o=new btnO7();
    else if(n==8)
        o=new btnO8();
    else
        o=new btnO9();
    o.name="o"+i+"_"+n;
    o.x=numX(n);
    o.y=numY(n);
    o.tabEnabled=false;
    o.visible=true;
    o.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,oHandler);
    addChild(o);
}
// if press the number, the number turn to green, that means, origin number will hedden, and clicked number show up
function oHandler(e:Event):void{
    if(canClick==true)
    {
        e.currentTarget.visible=false;
        var nam:String=e.currentTarget.name.substr(1);
        getChildByName("c"+nam).visible=true;
        var val:int=parseInt(e.currentTarget.name.substr(3));
        var pos:int=parseInt(e.currentTarget.name.substr(1,1));
            // to record which three numbers be pressed
        pickNum[count]=val;
            // to record where the three numbers be pressed, then the new three numbers be created should take place the number in the same place.
        pickArr[count]=pos;
        count++;
        sum+=val;
            // if pressed three number that match the goal, do animation of disappear
        if(count==3)
        {
            if(sum==goal)
            {
                score+=500;
                txScore.text=""+score;
                canClick=false;
                bubbleT.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
// function of create green numbers, show up when user click origin numbers
function clicked(n:int,i:int)
{
    var c:SimpleButton;
    if(n==1)
        c=new btnC1();
    else if(n==2)
        c=new btnC2();
    else if(n==3)
        c=new btnC3();
    else if(n==4)
        c=new btnC4();
    else if(n==5)
        c=new btnC5();
    else if(n==6)
        c=new btnC6();
    else if(n==7)
        c=new btnC7();
    else if(n==8)
        c=new btnC8();
    else
        c=new btnC9();
    c.x=numX(n);
    c.y=numY(n);
    c.name="c"+i+"_"+n;
    c.tabEnabled=false;
    c.visible=false;
    c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,cHandler);
    addChild(c);
}
// if user click the green number( SimpleButton) again, then cancel their option
function cHandler(e:Event):void{
    e.currentTarget.visible=false;
    var nam:String=e.currentTarget.name.substr(1);
    getChildByName("o"+nam).visible=true;
    var num:int=parseInt(e.currentTarget.name.substr(1,1));
    popout(num);
}
// pop out the numbers that user cancelled their option of the recording array
function popout(num:int)
{
    for(var i in pickArr)
    {
        if(pickArr[i]==num)
        {
            sum-=pickNum[i];
            pickNum[i]=0;
            pickArr[i]=0;
            count--;
            break;
        }
    }
}
// fix position of numbers
function numX(n:int)
{
    if(n==1||n==4||n==7)
        return 109.3;
    else if(n==2||n==5||n==8)
        return 274.3;
    else
        return 440.3;
}
function numY(n:int)
{
    if(n==1||n==2||n==3)
        return 161;
    else if(n==4||n==5||n==6)
        return 245;
    else
        return 330;
}
stop();
```

The code is in first frame, so I add stop() at final, I also remove event before I remove the old `SimpleSutton`.

The game link so far is:

[The bubble of numbers](https://googledrive.com/host/0B7hg_8WvMyfJbklyZkhkby1yZG8/CountBubble.html)

I'll add introduction page to thanks who help me in the game, thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you mind adding more comments to the code -- especially the bubbleoutHandler. There's a lot of code here and it would be helpful if you either reduced it to the non-working part or, at least, commented it well.

Answer (score 0):

What would happen if you defined the newT Timer in the code **before** you said: `newT.start()`?

Comment: I added, and hope you can click the link of the game to know what's wrong in the code, thank you!

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your game, and your English! Could you find an English speaker to help you post a more understandable question? What, exactly, do you want your game to do that it's not doing now?

Comment: This is a much better explanation! Thank you. I'll look more closely at this later today.

Comment: I found that is misunderstanding! The code is right, but the location( place) of the button is overlapped! So I misunderstand it not be created, thank you so much and sorry for costing your time so long~

Answer (score 0):

I arrange my code again, and found that I was misunderstand!

The buttons are all correct be created, but they are overlapped.

Now I fix it, thanks to you, [Craig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2359818/craig)!